# How to make a dialogue box in turtle take an input?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm a beginner with python and turtle. I want to make a dialogue box that asks a yes or no question. While I can get the box to pop up, how would I code it so that a "no" would close the turtle program and "yes" would keep it up? The part below the screen.textinput is wrong but I had it before for the terminal, and I imported turtle above.

```
    screen = turtle.getscreen()
screen.textinput("Welcome to Bowling!", "Are you readt to bowl?!")
if start.lower() == 'yes':
    print("Start!")
else:
    print("Goodbye!")
    turtle.clear
    turtle.bye()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

answer = screen.textinput("Welcome to Bowling!", "Are you ready to bowl?")

if answer is None or answer.lower().startswith('n'):
    print("Goodbye!")
    screen.clear()
    screen.bye()
else:
    print("Start!")
```

The key thing to remember is that `textinput()` returns the string the user typed or `None` if the user hits Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to cdlane's solution:

```
    import turtle
    
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    
    answer = turtle.simpledialog.askstring("Welcome to Bowling!", "Are you ready to bowl?")
    
    if answer is None or answer.lower().startswith('n'):
        print("Goodbye!")
        screen.clear()
        screen.bye()
    else:
        print("Start!")
```

Note: I have **not** tested this code yet, I just tweaked cdlane's code

There are other options to the `simpledialog` function.
There are the `askinteger` and `askfloat` for integers and floats respectively. I haven't fully understood these as I just found the function while exploring around with the code prediction of VSCode